# How to pass multiple parameters to $interval in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update `$scope.iterationCount` every time `$interval` is called.

How can I do that and call `vm.life.next` at the same time. `$scope.iterationCount` is supposed to increment by 1 after each `$interval` call.

```
function GameController($interval, board, life, $scope){
      var vm = this;

      $scope.time= "1000";
      vm.thumbs = [];
      vm.reset = reset;
      vm.load = load;
      vm.togglePlay = togglePlay;
      vm.save = save;
      $scope.iteration=10;
      $scope.userSelect = '\u25CF';
      $scope.w=15;
      $scope.h=15;
      $scope.gridColor = '#ffffff';
      $scope.iterationCount= 0;
      function togglePlay(){
        if(!vm.isStarted && vm.timer){ 
          $interval.cancel(vm.timer);
          vm.isStarted = false;
          return;
        }
        vm.isStarted = true;
        vm.timer = $interval(vm.life.next, $scope.time, $scope.iteration);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the doc of $interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) , the third param "count" is

> Number of times to repeat. If not set, or 0, will repeat indefinitely.

so, it won't increment , rather it stops the `$interval` execution after that counter is reached.

what you need to do is :

```
vm.timer = $interval(function(){
  vm.life.next();
  $scope.iteration++;
}, $scope.time);
```

[Here is a demo plunkr for better understanding](https://plnkr.co/edit/OrjS5TPLx1ozqOj6vs8A?p=preview)